# Is there a problem when defining exponential with negative base?

Tags: real-analysis

Well, this question may seem silly at first, but I'll make my point clear. Suppose $n \in \Bbb N$ and suppose $a \in \Bbb R$ is any number. Then the definition of $a^n$ is clear for any $a$ we choose. Indeed we define:

$$a^n = \prod_{k=1}^na$$

And even if $a$ is negative this has a meaning. Then we extend the definition for $n \in \Bbb Z$ and for $n \in \Bbb Q$. When we are to define to $n \in\Bbb R$ we define it as:

$$a^x=e^{x\ln a}$$

That's fine, but $\ln $ is a function defined on $\Bbb R^+$ so that if we try to compute $(-5)^\pi$ we'll get into trouble because this would be:

$$(-5)^{\pi}=e^{\pi \ln(-5)}$$

But $\ln (-5)$ is undefined. In that case, the function that $f : A \subset \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(a,x) = a^x$ would be undefined if $a < 0$, so that $A = \Bbb R^+ \times \Bbb R$. What I thought was: we can extend this function when $a$ is negative and $x$ is rational. In that case we would set it to the old definition of exponentiation, since we would have a real raised to a rational.

So, for negative base and irrational exponent the exponential remains undefined?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: . . . and I believe some programming languages will give you an error message if you try to raise an irrational number to a power.

Comment: @MichaelHardy:  all the ones I know accept positive numbers to powers (using $a^b=e^{b \log a}$) and negative numbers to integral powers (using multiply), but not negative numbers to non-integral powers.

Comment: I don't see how you are extending the definition to $n \in \mathbb Q$ if $a < 0$, unless you already want to pass to the complex numbers here. Take for instance $a = -1$ and $n = 1/2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends what number system you are working in.  In the reals, there is no answer.  In the complex numbers, there are many answers.  You can take the [principal branch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch) of the logarithm function, just saying that the imaginary part of the result will be in the range $(-\pi,\pi]$, in which case it is well defined.  But if $e^z=w$, it is also true that $e^{z+2i\pi k}=w$ for $k \in \Bbb Z$ so you could say $\log w=z + 2i \pi k$

Answer (score 2):

If $a < 0$ and $a \ne -1$, then it **is** possible to define $f(x) = a^x$, provided we restrict our domain to $a \in \{m / n : m$ is an integer and $n$ an **odd** positive integer$\}$. In this case, $a^{m/n} = \sqrt[n]{a^m}$.

For example, $(-8)^{-2/3} = 1/\sqrt[3]{(-8)^2} = 1/4$.

Comment: I think you should rewrite the formulae in TeX notation as required.