# Antiderivative of $\exp(x^2)$

Tags: integration

Can you please provide a step by step solution for next integral. I don't have any idea of how this can be solved $\displaystyle\int e^{x^2}\,dx$.

Comment: Pretty sure your function has no antiderivative since it is not elementary.

Comment: The function $e^{(x^2)}$ does not have an antiderivative expressible in terms of the usual elementary functions. If you mean $(e^x)^2$, that's easy, for then the function is $e^{2x}$.

Comment: Perhaps of similar interest: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530611/derivative-of-xx2

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215118/how-do-you-integrate-ex2)

Comment: This may be what you are looking for...http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking for the antiderivative of $e^{x^2}$ or are you looking to evaluate $\int_a^b e^{x^2}\,dx$ for specific values of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: In a 2nd term calc course, you probably were given the task of finding the definie integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{x^2}dx$. That is easy using the trick of multiplying by itself with a dummy argument of $y$ instead of $x$, then transforming to polar coordinates, where you get $2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty}re^{r^2}dr$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments $e^{x^2}$ does not have an antiderivative expressible in terms of  elementary functions.

In fact, $$\displaystyle\int e^{x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  \text{erfi}(x)$$ in which appears  the imaginary error function defined by $$\text{erfi}(x)=\frac{\text{erf(ix)}}{i}$$ with $$\text{erf(z)}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_0^ze^{-t^2}dt$$ which is a definition.