# Why is $y=b^x$ not continuous for $b>0$ and $b\ne 1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

The lines graphed by such do not have an interrupted domain.

So why is my textbook telling me this?

E: Typo in title. See photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b$ is a fixed number in the function, not the variable.

What your textbook says is that, for every (fixed) real number $b$ such that $b>0$ and $b\neq 1$, the function $y=b^x$ is a continuous function on the real line. The domain of this function is the set of all real numbers. No interruptions.

---

For exponential function (and the logarithm) the fixed number $b$ is called the basis. We do not consider the case $b=1$ simply because it is trivial (a constant function) and this trivial case behaves rather differently from the nontrivial cases.

Comment: Yes so why doesn't 1 provide a continuous function if it provides a straight line?

Comment: @user312484 see edits. It is not that it "doesn't provide a continuous function" but that it provides a rather trivial function.

Comment: oooooooooh. So why don't negative values work for b?

Comment: @user312484: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/415141/

Comment: The link was a little over my head but using the title as a search I got this "Because of their inability to consistently increase or decrease and restrictions on the domain, exponential functions cannot have negative bases." And Also saw that they create imaginary numbers which would make the function discontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

$y=b^x$ is continuous, the definition of continuous function is
Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in a point $c \in I$ if
$\forall \varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
When $|x-c|<0$ then $|f(x)-f(c)|< \varepsilon$
Or actually true
$f $ is continuous function in $c$ if
$\lim_{x \to c} f(x)=f(c)$
And ass other comments say the function
$y=b^x$ is continuous for $b\neq 0$
And for $b=1$ the function is constant

Answer (score 0):

Note that, for $b=1$ the function $y = \log_1 x$ is actually not defined for any $x \not =1$, as $1^y =1$ for all real $y$. For real $x \not =1$ there is no $y$ satisfying $1^y = x$. However for every other positive $b >0$ and every other positive $x$ the function $y = \log_b x$ is well-defined; equivalently there is a real number $y$ such that $b^y = x$.

However, $b^x$ is indeed defined for all $b >0$ including $b=1$. It is the horizontal line $y=1$.

The likely reason why $b =1$ was excluded even for the function $y = b^x$ is that for precisely $b>0$; $b \not =1$ the functions $y=b^x$ and $y=\log_b x$ are ***invertible***; in fact they pair up as each other's inverse; if $y=b^x$ then $x = \log_b y$.